Validate request body differently based on headers FastAPI
I have an endpoint called POST /account. Request body validations and fields change based on tenant. Tenant information is passed in the header.
Tenant1's request body example
{
  "account_id": "1234_56", // Value to be String
  "account_name": "abcd"
}

Tenant2's request body example
{
  "account_id": 1234, // Value to be Integer
  "account_name": "abcd",
  "created_date": "DD/MM/YYYY" // This doesn't exist in Tenant1's body
}

How do we declare different BaseModel classes for the same endpoint?
How can we handle validation of request body using pydantic based on tenant header?
How can we show this differently in swagger?

Can you include tenant field into the body data?
If yes, you can use discriminated unions: https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/unions/#discriminated-unions.

Does this answer your question?

Related answers could be found here and here as well.

Try setting the created_date as Optional in BaseModel like this
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
class Tenant(BaseModel):
    account_id: Union[int, str] = Field(union_mode='left_to_right')
    account_name:str
    created_date: Optional[date] = None


How can we manage different kind of validation for the account_id field?
Tenant1 has to send integer otherwise we should return a 400. But Tenant2 can send any string.

If you have only a few number of tenants it would be best to create a model for each tenant. You could then make use of discriminated Unions.
from datetime import date
from typing import Literal, Optional, Union

from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, RootModel, ConfigDict


class TenantBase(BaseModel):
    account_name: str

    model_config = ConfigDict(extra="forbid")


class Tenant1(TenantBase):
    account_id: Literal["1234_56"]


class Tenant2(TenantBase):
    account_id: Literal[1234]
    created_date: date


class Tenant(RootModel):
    root: Union[Tenant1, Tenant2] = Field(..., discriminator="account_id")


obj = Tenant.model_validate({"account_id": 1234, "account_name": "test", "created_date": "2022-01-01"})

